# Is there any point in using the constructor after construction when there is only one possible type

Tags: haskell

Considering

```
data Person = Person String Int
let p = Person "Jim" 23

let ofLegalAge :: Person -> Bool
    ofLegalAge (_ _ age) -- (instead of (Person _ age))
      | age >= 18 = True
      | age < 18  = False
```

Is there any point in ever using the *Enum* part of the sum type `Person` over the type of the sum type itself?
You can't add any variants anyway.

Comment: Terminology nitpick: `Person` is a product type, not a sum type. (A sum type would be `data Person = PersonName String | PersonId Int`.)

Comment: What is "the Enum part of the sum type `Person`"?

Comment: @duplode Well, is it? Isn't it equal to a tagged union, where there is only possible Enum value?

Comment: @DanielWagner By Enum part I mean (Person _ _), i.e. the first value in the sum type. I think in a very C kind of way (sum type as implemented by an enum and a union), that may be the root of some confusion.

Comment: Now I see what you mean, but the terminology mismatch does make things a bit confusing. The usual term for what you call "Enum part" is "constructor" (in Haskell, "Enum" usually refers to the `Enum` type class), and a "sum type" is one with two or more constructors.

Comment: I can't tell what the actual question here is.  Are you asking why the constructor is necessary when the type is known?  That's my best guess, but I'm not very confident in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question, with a few terminology tweaks:

> Is there any point in ever [specifying the constructor] `Person` [...]? You can't add any variants anyway.

In this case, given that there is just one constructor *and* that you have specified the type of `ofLegalAge`'s argument, specifying the constructor indeed is, in principle, redundant. In practice, though, there is no syntax for ommiting constructors in such a way. One alternative, which works very well for single-constructor types, is using record syntax:

```
data Person = Person
    { name :: String
    , age :: Int
    }

ofLegalAge :: Person -> Bool
ofLegalAge person
  | age person >= 18 = True
  | age person < 18  = False
```

Here, `age` is a `Person -> Int` function that gives access to the relevant field.

---

Tangential note: your function can be written more simply as...

```
ofLegalAge :: Person -> Bool
ofLegalAge person
  | age person >= 18 = True
  | otherwise = False
```

... and even more simply as:

```
ofLegalAge :: Person -> Bool
ofLegalAge person = age person >= 18
```